# Contenteditable Spacebar Click Does Not Register

Tags: html, contenteditable

I'm adding content editable to each element with "data-edit" attribute like this.

```
$element.find("[edit]").prop("contentEditable", "true");
```

I have one specific element in which when I edit text, the spacebar does not register and so I cant add white space between letters. the attribute on the element looks like this

```
<a href="#tabs-element-tab-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" data-edit contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">1</a>
```

Is there any known bug with contenteditable that can cause something like this?

Comment: Is the starting text always the single character "1"? I've experienced trouble when whitespace is added to the end of inline elements with contenteditable.

Comment: Its the only contenteditable element that has given me this issue and right now it is only 1 character. I changed it to "One" and the issue is still there.